# Firebase cloud functions executed several times

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I saw several topics about this problematic but sometimes it's juste due to few mistakes.

This is still a **real problem** for me and I did few experiences:

```
const addRoom = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("a")
    return Promise.resolve();
});
```

[image]

Same result without the Promise.resolve():

```
const addRoom = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("a")
});
```

[image]

(And of course I call the function just once on client side)

I created a web app and did few tests: 538 calls from cloud functions while it shouldn't exceed 100... I just can't believe this statistics, it's impossible. It's a serious issue.

What to do ?

Comment: Here's Firebase documentation on [why this happens](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees) and [how to deal with it](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#make_retryable_background_functions_idempotent).

Comment: "HTTP functions are invoked AT MOST once." Not sure about that...

Answer (score 6):

How I've dealt with this is to create a collection in Firestore which logs the `eventIds` and then check this each time I use a cloud function I want to be idempotent.

```
//Check if exists in event log
async function isIdempotenceOk(eventId) {
    console.log(eventId);
    let eventDoc = await 
admin.firestore().collection('events').doc(eventId).get();
    if (eventDoc.exists) {
        console.log('Event already processed');
        return false;
    } else {
        await admin.firestore().collection('events').doc(eventId).set({ eventId: eventId });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can call this in your other function like this:

```
const addRoom = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
console.log("a")

if(!await isIdempotenceOk(data.eventId)){return null;}
console.log('ok to continue')
return Promise.resolve();
});
```

This does mean you have a collection in Firestore which is called for each function which you perform this check on and there may be an alternative way for you to store the `eventIds` to check against.

Comment: Implemented something similar and thought it worth noting: Be careful that if you have two different cloud functions monitoring the same firestore path, your check will exit it out when you might not want.

Comment: Property 'eventId' does not exist on type 'CallableContext'

Comment: This solution seems like it should work, but I'm seeing that property `eventId` does not exist on type `CallableContext`. The TS definition for `CallableContext` does not define `eventId` as a property. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext

Comment: You're right you'd have to call from somewhere with an `EventContext` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext so in the above example you would have to pass it in via `data` instead. 

Where I've used this is for with `onCreate` for example: 
`exports.addRoom = functions.firestore
 .document('rooms/{roomId}')
 .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
              if (!await isIdempotenceOk(context.eventId)) { return null; }
              //continue
}`